# How to debug An SSRS error - "Input String was not in Correct Format"

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I know I've beem askimg alot, I am learning daly!

[image]

The offending expression is:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ResponseRange.Value = 3, Nothing, 
    IIf(Parameters!ResponseRange.Value is Nothing, Nothing,
        Parameters!ResponseRange.Value))
```

It's spec. because of this part - `Parameters!ResponseRange.Value is Nothing, Nothing,`

As for the Parameters, here's a screenshot of how they look - the Parameter is a "Text" data type:

[image]

Comment: I'll probably get in trouble for this, but don't worry about asking too much. At least you're asking the question. The community will let you know of any issues. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the `IIf()` checks in that expression are odd; generally you want to handle the "success" or the non-null cases first. Also, you can combine the two checks into one `IIf()`:

```
=IIf(Not IsNothing(Parameters!ResponseRange.Value) AndAlso 
    Parameters!ResponseRange.Value <> 3, Parameters!ResponseRange.Value, Nothing)
```

Note that I substituted the `IsNothing()` function for the `Is Nothing` expression. Other than that, the expression itself is valid. What is the data type for the `ResponseRange` parameter?  I'm deducing that it is an `Integer` via the comparison to `3`. Do you have it marked that it can be null? Primitive data types like `Integer` can't be set to `Nothing` like you're attempting if you haven't made them nullable.

You may need to set a default value of `0` or `-1` instead of `Nothing` and handle that subsequently in your query.

Comment: If 3 is a text value, make sure to compare the parameter to `"3"` (with the quotes), not to `3`.

Comment: Will do!  I'm getting very close now!

Comment: For some reason I'm having an issue passing a Null value along as a specified "Available Parameter" or as a "Default Parameter" .. yet if I run my Stored-Procedure manually in SSMS, like this `exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Respondent_Answer] '20121010', '20121011' , 18964 , null,   null , null` - it works... not sure whats goin on

Comment: Ah OK my issue may have to do with my Stored-proc., where it takes a big string of numbers like "10,11,12,13,14...120" and splits it. Because I'm getting an error about converting null to int.. (in SSMS" - `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'null' to data type int.` - except the value was reallly a varchar , not even null.  anyway i'm thinkin aloud you can carryon:)

Comment: In cases where SQL data types are ambiguous, use of a scalar function (instead of a stored procedure) with an embedded CASE-WHEN-ELSE structure can make life feel easier.